# If the user press ENTER without providing any values, the program will automatically set μ to 0 and σ2 to 1

Tags: python

Employ a Python program to ask the user to enter the mean and variance of the distribution. Tell the user that the mean can be any value between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞), but the variance must be a value larger than 0. Integrate certain control mechanism to ensure that the variance condition is fulfilled, and the input is numeric. If the user press ENTER without providing any values, the program will automatically set μ to 0 and σ2 to 1.

```
while True: 

    mean = int(input("please enter the mean of the distribution (any value between –∞ and +∞) "))
    variance = int(input("please enter the variance of the distribution (must be larger than 0) "))

    if variance >= 0:
        mean = (float(mean))
        variance = (float(variance))

        print(mean)
        print(variance)


    elif variance == int(""):
        mean = 0.0
        variance = 1.0

        print(variance)

    else:
        print("Variance input is smaller than zero")
        break
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: You may want to write two separate `while` loops, one for the `mean` input and one for the `variance` input. Design each loop so that it is only exited if the input fulfills the conditions.

Comment: I am unable to get the program running if the user press ENTER without providing values, the program will automatically set μ to 0 and σ2 to 1.

Comment: Writing int(input('Prompt')) is a bad idea because if the input cannot be interpreted as an integer, you'll get a ValueError exception. Consider using try/except. int("") will induce ValueError

Comment: As Andy says, don't convert the input to integer immediately. If you keep the input as a string at first, you can check for an empty input and adjust the value accordingly, e.g.: `if mean == '':
    mean = 0`